# How to convert for loop to a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

Hello friend i have two array and i want to match id id of them and concetanate them in the new array.

This is my `$dizi1`;

```
$dizi1 = [
[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'özkan',
    'surname' => 'özdemir',
],
[
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'çağrı',
    'surname' => 'uğurel',
],
[
    'id' => 3,
    'name' => 'can',
    'surname' => 'tokay'
],
[
    'id' => 4,
    'name' => 'lütfü',
    'surname' => 'uzun'
],
[
    'id' => 5,
    'name' => 'ahmet',
    'surname' => 'yeni',
],
[
    'id' => 6,
    'name' => 'rabia',
    'surname' => 'papatya',
],
[
    'id' => 7,
    'name' => 'canan',
    'surname' => 'tokatlı'
],
[
    'id' => 8,
    'name' => 'muhammet',
    'surname' => 'uzundal'
]
];
```

and this is mu `$dizi2`;

```
$dizi2 = [
[
    'id' => 2,
    'birthday' => 1993
],
[
    'id' => 3,
    'birthday' => 1990
],
[
    'id' => 4,
    'birthday' => 1989
],
[
    'id' => 1,
    'birthday' => 1987
],
[
    'id' => 5,
    'birthday' => 1993
],
[
    'id' => 7,
    'birthday' => 1990
],
[
    'id' => 6,
    'birthday' => 1989
],
[
    'id' => 8,
    'birthday' => 1987
]
];
```

Then i tried defined a new array

```
$newarray = $dizi1;
```

and then i tried that

```
foreach($dizi1 as $k)
{
foreach ($newarray as $i)
{
    if ($newarray[$i]['id'] == $dizi2[$i]['id']) 
    {

        $newarray[$i]['birthday'] = $dizi2[$i]['birthday'];
    }
  }
 }
```

now it is not working.

I have to use foreach and i will also use it for excel file.

What is wrong?

Comment: You are setting the value from if `$dizi1['birthday']` matches `$dizi2['birthday']`. That's equal to giving the instruction, enter all rooms, if the wall is yellow paint it yellow. It's a pointless exercise because it doesn't provide a changed state.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_search` and `array_column` inside loop I used `array_map`

```
$result = array_map (
  function ($item) use($dizi2) { 
    $index = array_search($item['id'], array_column($dizi2, 'id'));
    if($index >= 0){
      $item['birthday'] = $dizi2[$index]['birthday'];
    }
    return $item ;
  },$dizi1
);
print_r($result);
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1001514)

You will get output as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => özkan
            [surname] => özdemir
            [birthday] => 1987
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => çağrı
            [surname] => uğurel
            [birthday] => 1993
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => can
            [surname] => tokay
            [birthday] => 1990
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => lütfü
            [surname] => uzun
            [birthday] => 1989
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => ahmet
            [surname] => yeni
            [birthday] => 1993
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => rabia
            [surname] => papatya
            [birthday] => 1989
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => canan
            [surname] => tokatlı
            [birthday] => 1990
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => muhammet
            [surname] => uzundal
            [birthday] => 1987
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank u sir but i am junior developer. For example i can not understand use function or array map function. I have to use foreach interms of performance. Thank's for care! :)

Comment: @Cugurel : do you want the same output as above ?

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
foreach($dizi1 as $k)
{
foreach ($dizi2 as $i)
{
    if ($i['id']==$k['id']) 
    {

        $newarray[$i['id']]['birthday'] = $i['birthday'];
    }
  }
 }
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newarray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [birthday] => 1987
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [birthday] => 1993
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [birthday] => 1990
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [birthday] => 1989
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [birthday] => 1993
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [birthday] => 1989
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [birthday] => 1990
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [birthday] => 1987
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newarray = [];
foreach($dizi1 as $d1){
   foreach ($dizi2 as $d2){
      if ($d1['id'] == $d2['id']){
         $newarray[] = array_merge($d1, $d2);
         break;
      }else{
         $newarray[] = $d1;
         $newarray[] = $d2;
      }
   }
}
```

You will get output as:

```
[
    [
            [id] => 1,
            [name] => özkan,
            [surname] => özdemir,
            [birthday] => 1987
    ],
    [
            [id] => 2,
            [name] => çağrı,
            [surname] => uğurel,
            [birthday] => 1993
    ],
    [
            [id] => 3,
            [name] => can,
            [surname] => tokay,
            [birthday] => 1990
    ],
    [
            [id] => 4,
            [name] => lütfü,
            [surname] => uzun,
            [birthday] => 1989
    ],
    [
            [id] => 5,
            [name] => ahmet,
            [surname] => yeni,
            [birthday] => 1993
    ],
    [
            [id] => 6,
            [name] => rabia,
            [surname] => papatya,
            [birthday] => 1989
    ],
    [
            [id] => 7,
            [name] => canan,
            [surname] => tokatlı,
            [birthday] => 1990
    ],
    [
            [id] => 8,
            [birthday] => 1987
    ]
]
```